# Parallel Route slot apply to all child routes with almost identical layout styles

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I would like to use my reusable input component in all my child routes in dashboard route such as library, project, message. These child route have similar layout, but not identical, but I would like my input component to stay at the bottom of the page inside those child route.

One way, of course, is to add it as a parallel routes to all my child routes, but I wish a more elegant way to achieve it in the context of nextjs, right now can't think of a way to do it.

here is an example of my child route, dashboard/project, all other child routes have similar layout but I need @input parallel route to stay at the bottom of my dashboard route.

```
<Box className="dashboard_menu">{list}</Box>
  <Box className="dashboard_main">
  <Box className="dashboard_main_flex">
    <Box className="dashboard_main_flex-section">
      <Box className="dashboard_main_flex-section-content">{main}</Box>
      <Box className="dashboard_main_flex-section-input">{input}</Box>
    </Box>
  </Box>
</Box>
```

here is my folder structure:

```
(dashboard)
 ┗ dashboard
 ┃ ┣ @input
 ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┣ library
 ┃ ┃ ┣ @list
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ @main
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ @card
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ layout.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ layout.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┣ message
 ┃ ┃ ┣ @list
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ @window
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ layout.tsx
 ┃ ┣ project
 ┃ ┃ ┣ @list
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ @main
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ @purchase
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ @sales
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ @table
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ default.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ layout.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ page.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┣ layout.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┣ qc
 ┃ ┃ ┣ layout.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┣ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┃ ┗ page.tsx
 ┃ ┣ error.tsx
 ┃ ┣ layout.tsx
 ┃ ┣ loading.tsx
 ┃ ┗ page.scss
```